# eledpar doesn't respect changes of line spacing

Tags: fontsize, line-spacing

I try to typeset a bilingual text on facing pages. For this I use the eledmac/eledpar packages. The latin text on the even pages should get displayed larger than the translation on the odd pages. However, within the environments of the `eledpar` package, the linespread does not get sufficiently increased.

The difference to a normal paragraph outside the environments of `eledpar` with larger font size is small but noticeable and leads to a suboptimal outcome.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[latin,english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{eledmac,eledpar}
\begin{document}
\begin{pages}\numberlinefalse{}
  \begin{Leftside}\large \selectlanguage{latin}
    \beginnumbering
    \pstart \blindtext \blindtext \pend
    \endnumbering
    \par
  \end{Leftside}

  \begin{Rightside}\selectlanguage{english}
    \beginnumbering
    \pstart \blindtext \blindtext \pend
    \endnumbering
  \end{Rightside}
  \Pages
\end{pages}

The following has correct line spacing
\selectlanguage{latin}
{\large
  \blindtext \blindtext\par
}
\end{document}
```

Am I doing something wrong?

(The `parallel` package seems to work correctly, but it is not an option for me as it can't set even basic footnotes on the pages which are typeset in parallel.)

EDIT: I get the impression that `eledpar` doesn't respect alterings of the line spacing at all -- see this MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[latin,english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{eledmac,eledpar}
\begin{document}
\begin{pages}\numberlinefalse{}
  \begin{Leftside}\selectlanguage{latin}
    \beginnumbering
    \pstart \linespread{1.5}\selectfont \blindtext \blindtext \par \pend
    \endnumbering
  \end{Leftside}

  \begin{Rightside}\selectlanguage{english}
    \beginnumbering
    \pstart \blindtext \blindtext \pend
    \endnumbering
  \end{Rightside}
  \Pages
\end{pages}

{\selectlanguage{latin} \linespread{1.2}\selectfont \blindtext \blindtext\par}
\end{document}
```

Comment: open an issue on eledpar github account. It should be solvable if we modifiy eledpar code.