# How to place parallel text on two pages?

Tags: reledpar, parallel-texts

How to place parallel text on two pages?

*Lorem ipsum...* and *Sed saqittis...* are original texts (paragraphs).
*Maecenas...* and *Aliquam...* are translated texts (paragraphs).

I read about reledmac and reledpar, but I can't put the title (`\huge{\textbf{Title}}` works, but there's not a section anyway) and also there's no way to leave blank line between paragraphs. (`\pstart[\vline]` doesn't work).

Is there some way to create kind of this document?
[image: expected result]

Comment: Welcome! Have you seen https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/557349/ ?

Comment: @Thérèse as I understand I solved two problems: 1) line between paragraphs; 2) header placement. [source](https://pastebin.com/Kg5fzrCq). Thanks!