# Any packages for typesetting a diglot edition?

Tags: xetex

I searched the TeX Stack Exchange, and also the internet in general, in search of options for typesetting a diglot edition of any sort. However, I didn't find anything. This seems like it would be a common request, so I was wondering if anyone knows of packages that might help me typeset a diglot edition using LaTeX.

Comment: What is a diglot edition?

Comment: Search for 'bilingual typesetting in TeX', then you will probably find some packages. See e.g. `reledmac`. (Also a recommendation for you, @PeterWilson ;-)

Comment: Which aspects do you want help with? Is https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/557349 the kind of thing you want?

Comment: Yes! Just glancing at it, the reledmac package especially looks like it might be helpful. Thank you.